# How can I convert String to Double without losing precision in Java?

Tags: java

Tried as below

```
String d=new String("12.00");
Double dble =new Double(d.valueOf(d));
System.out.println(dble);
```

Output:
12.0

But i want to get 12.00 precision

please let me know correct way without using format() method in string class

Comment: A double is a number. 12.0 and 12.00 are the same number.

Comment: You can use `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: You didn't lose precision. It is precisely the same number.

Comment: You don't have to do `String d=new String("12.00");`, you may simply do `String d="12.00";`

Comment: @ user: If you're going to say things like "...without using `format()`...", explain **why** you have to not do that. Otherwise it's like saying "I need to unscrew this screw, what's the best way of doing that without using this screwdriver I have right here?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) Instead of a double:

```
String d = "12.00"; // No need for `new String("12.00")` here
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(d);
```

This works because `BigDecimal` maintains a "precision," and the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor sets that from the number of digits to the right of the `.`, and uses it in `toString`. So if you just dump it out with `System.out.println(decimal);`, it prints out `12.00`.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is not a loss of precision, but the output format of your number and its number of decimals. You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to solve your problem.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String d = new String("12.00");
Double dble = new Double(d.valueOf(d));
System.out.println(formatter.format(dble));
```

I will also add that you can use [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) to choose which decimal separator to use. For example, a point :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols separator = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
separator.setDecimalSeparator('.');
```

Then, while declaring your `DecimalFormat` :

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00", separator);
```

Comment: So instead of `String#format` (which the OP said he/she didn't want to use), `DecimalFormat#format`. I'm thinking if he/she doesn't want `String#format`, this won't be very helpful. (**Why** he/she should want to avoid the obvious tool for the job, I don't know...)

Comment: I have to agree, I don't know what he means by _correct way without using_ `String#format`.

Answer (score 2):

You have not lost any precision, 12.0 is exactly equal to 12.00. If you want to display or print it with 2 decimal places, use `java.text.DecimalFormat`

Comment: 12.0 could represent 11.95 to 12.04

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format output, use [PrintStream#format(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.format("%.2f%n", dble);
```

There `%.2f` - two places after decimal point and `%n` - newline character.

### UPDATE:

If you don't want to use `PrintStream#format(...)`, use [`DecimalFormat#format(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).