# Convert String to Long android

Tags: java, android

I have value String "2248880.0" , i want to convert to Long in android with code :

```
Long.parseLong( "2248880.0");
```

But I have get Error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2248880.0"

so How to fix it ?

Comment: `double d= Double.parseDouble("2248880.0");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423491/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-without-losing-precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this -

```
long value = (long) Double.parseDouble("2248880.0");
```

This will cast your answer(which is `double` type) to `long` type.

Answer (score 7):

This is not Long value, so you need to parse it as Double or Float first. After that you can cast it to Long.

Or you can remove .000 from the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2248880.0"
```

> NumberFormatException is an Exception that might be thrown when you
>   try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an
>   int , a float , or any other Java numeric type.

At first remove `.`

Then Use.

`long YourLongObj = Long.parseLong("Your_string");`

Please read **[How can I convert String to Double without losing precision in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298232/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-without-losing-precision-in-java)**

Answer (score 2):

First Declare a Long Variable:

```
long l;
```

Then Initialize it:

```
l= (long) Double.parseDouble("2248880.0");
```

This is because the value you have is in double format, so you have to first parse it into double and then from double to long.